# Create an option value for product attribute when importing a product

Tags: magento-1.7, import, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport, custom-options

I am importing products with the help of avs-fastsimeplimport. The way I do it is I create an array with keys - the name of the attribute, and values - the corresponding value for that attribute that I get from an XML. If some value of an option does not exist (but I have it in the XML), then it is being created on the fly. before I'd do it like this:

```
creating some parts of the import array...
$this->_createOptionValueIfNotExists('manufacturer', (string)value);
$importArray['manufacturer'] = (string)value;
creating some more parts of the import array...
```

and at the end, when the array is created, another method is called, that does the job with the AVS-fastsimpleimport module.

But now I should move this creation of option values into another class. And it comes after creating the array but BEFORE calling the function that actually does the importing process. I get exception (custom made) that notifies me, that the value set for ['manufacturer'] is invalid, and then gives me a list of the possible options, where I can actually see also the newly created option...!

I experimented with putting `die();` before and after the function that does the importing of the created array:

- if I put it before - I don't even get the exception (which means the error happens when I try to import the array values), and when I go to the back-end I can see my newly created value for that option (and the importing hasn't happened at that point).
- if I put it after - I ofcourse get the exception... (because it is almost a complete process of importing).

Summarizing: if I create the option value before I set the value for that value into the product array, to be imported, it works. If I create the option value after the value is set into the product array - it is saved in the back-end before the importing takes place, but I still get exception. And the bad part is that it is basically not possible to create the option value before I set the value in the array in another way than it's now. And I don't want that way.

**UPDATE:**
Can be closed.

Comment: The option values are probably in a static cache generated the first time they are requested, if you create it before this cache is populated it ends up there, otherwise not.

Comment: You can set the value in the array, you just need to create the new options before the actual import classes load the available options. Please provide more context of the new code you are intending to use.

Comment: @Cags - so what you're saying is that I have to create the option values before this cache is populated or not? Or this was just an explanation why I can see the newly created value, but cannot use it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module. Please contact them directly for support.